# Cwrsync Paths: change_dir failed: No such file or directory

Tags: rsync, windows-11, cwrsync

I want to use rsync on Windows for a project. As a test,  I'm trying to use [cwrsync](https://itefix.net/cwrsync) to sync the folder `C:\Users\Name\Pictures\Test1` to `C:\Username\Name\Pictures\Test2`. I ran the command `rsync -a C:\Users\Name\Pictures\Test1 C:\Users\Name\Pictures\Test2` and got

```
The source and destination cannot both be remote.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1426) [Receiver=3.2.7]
```

I then tried `rsync -a c/Users/Name/Pictures/Test1 c/Users/Name/Pictures/Test2` and then got

```
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/cygdrive/c/Users/Name/Pictures/c/Users/Nia/Pictures" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: [Receiver] change_dir#3 "/cygdrive/c/Users/Name/Pictures/c/Users/Nia/Pictures" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(827) [Receiver=3.2.7]
```

How should I be formmating my paths for cwrsync on Windows?